# Textfield and button not staying inline in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a css/html related problem that's really annoying me :(

I have a div which is 600px
An input text field of width 500px
A button of width 100px

```
<div id="search">
     <input type="text" id="search_bar" class="search_bar" name="q"/>
     <button id="search_videos" class="cool_button">Search</button>
</div>
```

The button and input tag have a bunch of CSS3 properties
It seems fine in firefox, however the button goes onto the next line in Chrome. Is there a CSS I'm missing to adjust the width so it always stays inline?
Thanks

EDIT:

Heres the fiddle :)

http://jsfiddle.net/eGyRU/

Comment: Can you post your CSS? Or even better a fiddle. Tough to guess what css property is triggering the wrap.

Comment: In most box model renderings, the borders count as width, so you need to take that into account. Your width is actually like 604px because of the borders on each side of the buttons...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current  width is 521px, not 500px. This happens because you must add both width and padding values to obtain final width = 500px + 0.4em x 2 (left and right padding).
It will be solved if you set input width to 479px.

Answer (score 0):

Actually web browsers sometimes differ in implementing different attributes. 
Here the problem might be due to the **padding** property of the elements.
So to make it work either you should try to reduce the **width** of one of your **input or button** elements or simply increase the **width** of your **"div"** tag.